# Magento 2 timezones

Tags: mysql, timezone, magento2, magento-2.0

I have a problem with getting datetime in magento 2 collection.

for example this is database data:

```
entity_id | paid_at
------------------------------------------
        1 | 2016-12-13 07:30:39
```

full database query:

```
CREATE TABLE `pmnt` (
    `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
    `paid_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Payment date',
    PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='pmnt'
```

and magento collection returns:

```
[
    'entity_id' => 1
    'paid_at' => '2016-12-13 06:30:39'
]
```

this is returned on Zend_Db_Select level, wrong date is on grids, forms, collections, loads.

what is weird, table cms_block seems to be ok. I mean same updated_at and created_at are both in db and magento collections.

I tried to set timezone in bootstrap.php but then cms_block collection gets wrong datetime.

```
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($tableName)
    ->addColumn(
        'entity_id',
        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        [
            'identity' => true,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'primary'  => true,
        ],
        'ID'
        )
    ->addColumn(
        'paid_at',
        Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        [
            'nullable' => true
        ],
        'Payment date'
    );
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What's the MySQL data type of your `paid_at` column? What tool did you use to retrieve the *database data* shown in the example at the top of your question?

Comment: hi, paid_at is timestamp, I edited my post full table query is on top. To get this data from table I tried to use: phpmyadmin, phpstorm db tool, and commandline mysql tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, `TIMESTAMP` data types are always stored in UTC.  When an application (like the command line mysql tool or magento) puts a time value into MySQL to be stored in a timestamp, that time value is *always* translated from the current setting of `time_zone` to UTC.  When an application retrieves a `TIMESTAMP` value, it is always translated from UTC to the current `time_zone` setting.  So, when you say *this is database data*, it's hard to know what is actually stored without knowing your current time zone setting.

Comment: I just change this field to datetime, same - wrong - effect. Also table cms_block in same database also has go fields with timestamp and values getted by collection is correct.
timestamp is Europe/Warsaw, mysql database is set to SYSTEM both in global and session

Comment: Seems you were right. I changed this column type. Cache wasn't clean so I didn't get correct result. Anyway I still have no idea where why magento sets incorrect time_zone :/

Answer (score 0):

In Ui component grid admin. You can display the column paid_at via timezone of your store by this code:

The file app/code/vendor/Your Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/listing.xml

```
<column name="paid_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Paid At</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">8</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am doing. as I said, the problem is not in ui component. I am getting wrong data on collection load level.

Answer (score 0):

your server timezone is not same as magento time zone setting in back end.

in direct sql query your are getting result with server time zone.
and in magento collection same data will convert according to setting time zone .